# Запуск браузера

Tags: netbeans

Вопрос простой, но никак не могу найти в инете. Когда запускаю проект через NetBeans, он запускает его через ГуглХром, а мне нужно через Эксплоер(IE). Не могу найти нужную настройку, пробовал ставить интернет эксплорер браузер по умолчанию - не помогло.

Answer (score 2):

Меню Tools-options раздел General поле Web Browser, выберите нужный браузер